# How To classify Read and Unread news in Feed Reader?

Tags: c#, wpf, feed

I am working on a RSS Feed module in WPF Application. I am getting news items in xml document from the httpWebResponse. I want to calssify the unread feeds. How can we identify the user read or Unread the news article ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the web pages linked by RSS feed are opened.

If they are opened within your app using a WebBrowser control, then you must track history of read feeds yourself within your app. See [WPF WebBrowser Recent Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113237/wpf-webbrowser-recent-pages).

You can use [the `Navigated` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the `WebBrowser` control.

If they are opened using a particular web browser, then you can eventually read somehow the history of that particular browser. But when the history gets deleted, your read/unread status gets deleted as well.